# How to install numpy for Python 2 with choco?

Tags: chocolatey

I want to use [chocolately](https://chocolatey.org) to install [numpy](https://chocolatey.org/packages/numpy) onto a Windows machine.

However when I run:

```
choco install numpy
```

it tried to install a numpy for Python 3.

How can I force it to install a version for Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I install `numpy` for Python 2 with `choco`?

Run `choco install numpy`.

> When I ran `choco install numpy`, it tried to install `numpy` for Python 3. How can I force it to install a version for Python 2?

The trick here is that if you look at the `chocolateyinstall.ps1` and `chocolateyuninstall.ps1` files for the [Chocolatey numpy package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/numpy) you've linked to (under `Files`), the package itself simply uses the version of Python installed on your system, along with Python's `pip` package manager, to install and uninstall Python packages.

Therefore, the simplest way to handle this is to:

- Add Python 2.7 (e.g. `C:/path/to/Python27`) your Windows path variable(s) and remove/rename any entry for e.g. Python 3.7.
- Log off and then back on to reload your path variable(s). Open a command prompt and check that `python -V` returns e.g. `Python 2.7.16`.
- Run `choco install numpy`. Say no to installing e.g. Python 3.7 and yes to installing `numpy`. As long as there is an entry in green that says `numpy` was installed successfully, you can likely ignore any other messages/errors.

To verify that `numpy` was installed successfully, run `python` from a command window and enter `import numpy` at the interactive `>>>` prompt. If there is no error message, `numpy` has been imported successfully.

**Caveats**

This method obviously relies on Python 2.7 being the default `python` on your system. If this changes, you may run into issues in the future.

**Notes**

Alternatively, since Chocolatey is simply using `pip` in the background, you can use e.g. `C:/path/to/Python27/python.exe -m pip install numpy` to install `numpy` directly (minus an entry in Chocolatey).

Comment: I really want to automate the process (part of terraform provisioning process). log off and back is not going to work for my situation.

Comment: To be clear, logging off and on is only required if your are changing Python versions (to reload path variables). If Python 2.7 is already the default `python` (i.e. Python 3 isn't in your path or you taken other "mitigating" steps such as renaming the Python 3 executable), there should be no need for that particular step.

Comment: Obviously, you would still need to say 'no' to installing Python 3.7.